# How to format the PHP output of a form action properly?

Tags: php, forms, post, text-files, fwrite

I will like to save the output of the following form action in a textfile like this:

```
var1
var2
var3
```

Example form action:

```
<form action="myform.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="var1" value="var1">
<input type="hidden" name="var2" value="var2">
<input type="hidden" name="var3" value="var3">

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Example myform.php

```
<?php

  $fs = fopen("mydata.txt","w");
  fwrite($fs,$_POST['var1']);
  fwrite($fs, "\n");
  fwrite($fs,$_POST['var2']);
  fwrite($fs, "\n");
  fwrite($fs,$_POST['var3']);
  fwrite($fs, "\n");
  fclose($fs);


?>
```

However, the output is:

```
var1var2var3
```

What could i do to fix it?

Comment: Are you using windows? try `\r\n` then.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im post it as answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows you will not see those variables in new lines. This is because Windows uses `\r\n` as line terminator.

`var1\nvar2\nvar3\n` in windows will render as

```
var1var2var3
```

But in Linux or Unix (`\n` line terminating) it will render as

```
var1
var2
var3
```

So you have to use `\r\n` instead of `\n` like this

```
fwrite($fs, "\r\n");
```

This will render the values in new line on any operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do it for debugging purpose or for actual storage in your application?
Either way if it is not supposed to be read by users directly as a text file you can save your POST array using var_export function.

```
<?php
file_put_contents("C:/debug.txt", var_export($_POST, true));
?>
```

When you use var_export, what you get in file is a valid PHP code, so if you want later on you can use it as an array and get your data back in application.

Answer (score 0):

A predefined constant `PHP_EOL` is available in PHP4 since PHP 4.3.10 and in PHP5 since PHP 5.0.2.

It will add correct end of line for any operating system.

```
fwrite($fs, PHP_EOL);
```

Use this if you are developing your project in one operating system and deploy it in a server that is running a different operating system.